# bulk update data in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have below data in stored in my db. The use case is the user can choose date and update the age or name in bulk. How will be the query look like?

```
[
    {
        date:'1-1-2016',
        users:[
            {
                'name':'james',
                'age':18
            },
            {
                'name':'alice',
                'age':20
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        date:'2-1-2016',
        users:[
            {
                'name':'james',
                'age':18
            },
            {
                'name':'alice',
                'age':20
            },
            {
                'name':'xiaomi',
                'age':29
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I used this `Users.update({date:'1-1-2016','user.name':'james'},{'$set':'users.$.age':5}})`
 but it's not bulk update, it only update single document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set multi true option in mongodb update

ex. if you want to update multiple document use

Users.update({date:'1-1-2016','user.name':'james'},{'$set':'users.$.age':5}}, {multi:true})

but if there is many dates to match use

Users.update({date:{ $in: [ '1-1-2016','1-2-2016' ] },'user.name':'james'},{'$set':'users.$.age':5}}, {multi:true})

Comment: `$in` make sense here, finally I got an answer thank you so much!

Comment: As I have noted, `update` is deprecated function. Please do not use it in meaningful code!

Comment: @DmitryFrolov what should I use then?

Comment: @JessieEmerson in a case of update you should use `updateOne` or `updateMany` (it depends on your aims). Official docs are here http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`updateMany`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#updateMany). It is a special function for bulk update. Please note `update` is [deprecated](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#update).

Comment: Example: `db.collection('A').updateMany({"repetitions.today": {$gt: 0}},
{$set: { "repetitions.today": 0 }
});`. I think in your case you just need to replace `update` by `updateMany`. Please, try?

Comment: not as simple as that. My single query accept one date, how does that work when user selected multiple dates?

Comment: OK. In this case, you can use `$in` predicate: `"date": {$in: []}`